# Import text file in phpMyAdmin

Tags: mysql, sql, phpmyadmin

I have a `text` file that contains about 1200-lines. I want to import it in phpMyAdmin as a table where a primary `id` will be given to each line. 
Is there a way to achieve this in phpMyAdmin?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. Create the table into which you want the data to be inserted:

   ```
   CREATE TABLE my_table (
     id        SERIAL,
     my_column TEXT
   );
   ```
2. On the `Import` tab, select your file and then under `Format of imported file`:

   - Choose `CSV using LOAD DATA`
   - Ensure that the `Fields ... by` options are all blank
   - Leave `Lines terminated by` as `auto`
   - Under Column names, specify the name of the column into which you want the data to be inserted - i.e. `my_column` above
   - Click `Go`

Comment: When I do this, I get the error of "Invalid parameter for CSV import: Columns terminated by "

Answer (score 0):

It works if you select the "CSV" format and fill out the column name manually